# Problem with refreshing data from API via Safari

Tags: jquery, api, safari, setinterval

I'm building an online radio player and I'm taking data from an API (AirTime platform) based on the code below. It's working fine everywhere except via Safari, where it sometimes refreshes data in few seconds and sometimes in more than a minute.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    jQuery.getJSON('https://api-airtime...', function(data) {
      var text = `<span id="player-api-track" class="player-api">${data.tracks.current.name}</span>`;
      jQuery('.schedule-airtime').html(text);
    });
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: If the code works, but with delays, then it's a server side issue. If you're making a request to the third-party API every 3 seconds it's possible you're being rate-limited due to too many requests being sent.

Comment: I've tried to set longer time for setInterval but there's still delay. And it's working perfect on Chrome (Windows/Android), Firefox and Opera, only on Safari there's "random" delay.

Comment: I've also found out that via Safari it sometimes even don't send requests to API server - only the first one (like setTimeout) and after that silence.